# unexpected session identifier php

Tags: php, json, session, indexing, undefined

So I looked into other threads but didnt find a solution that worked for me.
Here is my problem:
I have two php pages:
http://codepad.org/VhblM76K and 
http://codepad.org/W9bz8L3E.

The first page is supposed to get information from a form, look for it in a database, store it in a variable `$_SESSION['$dataArray']` and send it to the second page.

On the second page I get the information in javascript from php with json_encode, which gives an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < result.php:20.
```

When I look in the source in chrome it says:

```
var schoolData = <br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: $dataArray in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\highschools.bg\result.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
null;
```

How is this an unidentified index, when i can only go to the second page after visiting the first one, where I assing a value to `$_SESSION['$dataArray']`.

How can I fix this? I have written `session_start()` in both pages and it didnt work for me.
I need the variable `schoolData` to show the information on the page.

Comment: You know you don't need to prepend your array keys with a `$`? $_SESSION['dataArray']`. Also, your submit input button needs the attribute `name="submit"`. It has a value, but no name, so its not submitted as a form data attribute. Also, where's your redirect to the second page? I can't see anything that redirects in the first page?

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.Fixed the name on the button. In the form i have action="result.php" which redirects to the second page.

Comment: In that case, if you are redirecting to your second page after clicking the form, the session data isn't being set at all. You need to redirect to the same page, then in your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` conditional, you need to put the redirect in there at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the error is because you're not setting any session data, because you are redirecting directly to the second page from the form.

You need to update the form so it redirects back to the same page the form is on, then replace your PHP code with the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'highschools';

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $givenCity = $_POST['city'];
    $givenClass = $_POST['class'];
    $givenName = $_POST['name'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,
        "SELECT * FROM highschools WHERE name like '%$givenName%' AND city like '%$givenCity%' AND class like '%$givenClass%'; ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $_SESSION['dataArray'] = array();
    while($row_count > 0) {
        $curRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['dataArray'][] = $curRow;
        $row_count--;
    }

    header('location: http://YOUR_SECOND_PAGE_ADDRESS');
```

Notice, the only line I've added is the last line, `hedaer('location: ... ');`

Don't forget to change the `http://YOUR_SECOND_PAGE_ADDRESS` to the actual page address of your second piece of code.

Then in the second page, replace `$_SESSION['$dataArray']` with `$_SESSION['dataArray']`

and it should work.

Comment: Im sorry but I'm new at php, so is the header location supposed to look like some of these:     header('location: result.php'); or header('location: http://localhost/highschools.bg/result.php'); ? None of them works for me for some reason.

Comment: I've posted some code on the same site you posted, this should be your first page: http://codepad.org/ghZRtiog and this should be your second (result.php): http://codepad.org/wbrGYsh5 Both files should be in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I used your code and it did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are writing the session as `$_SESSION['$dataArray']`. If you have a variable somewhere called `$dataArray` then you need to write it `$_SESSION[$dataArray]`.

Alternately, if you don't have a variable named `$dataArray`, then you need to write it as `$_SESSION['dataArray']`.

EDIT:
Try `print_r($_SESSION)` beneath the `session_start()` at the top of the page and see if you have set that the `$_SESSION['dataArray']`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // See if the session contains your $_SESSION['dataArray']
    // If not, you can force it to have a default value to avoid errors
     print_r($_SESSION);
    $_SESSION['dataArray'] = (isset($_SESSION['dataArray']))? $_SESSION['dataArray']:array(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Намерени училища</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contentWrapper" style="height:1000px;">
            <header id="pageHeader">
            </header>
            <section id="schoolsContainer">
                <ul id="schoolsList"></ul>
            </section>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="navTemplate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var schoolData = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['dataArray']) ?>;
            for (var i = 0; i < schoolData.length; i++) {
                console.log(schoolData[i]['name']);
                console.log(schoolData[i]['id']);
            }
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

On the other page, this also has to be set before it works:

```
$_SESSION['dataArray'] = array();
      while($row_count > 0) {
                $curRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $_SESSION['dataArray'][] = $curRow;
                $row_count--;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't have a variable called $dataArray, so I removed the dollar sign from the indexes. It didn't fix it though. Now it says: Undefined index: dataArray.

Comment: Let me examine more closer your code. That only took care of one error then.

Comment: So I did everything. When I gave it a default value that did got rid of the error, but it just produced an empty array, which isn't really what I wanted. So I moved all the php code in the second page and it seems to work now. I didn't want it to be all in one place but it seems that that's the way it's going to be. Still thanks very much for the help.

Comment: To make it cleaner, you can `include()` the one page into the other but keep them separate or better yet make your processing script a class method and just run it on that page.